# Help with Shadow compositing

Tags: compositing-nodes, shader-nodes, shadows, scene

Hello Blender community.

I want to make a shadow effect like in these screenshots, but my compositing skill is not enough to do this.

I want to make a fan animation for this game. I recreated the location but I can't recreate the shadow effect. I tried to change the contrast of the black through the hue node, but the contrast of the entire scene was changing, not just the shadows.

Can you tell me how I can achieve the same effect?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It's impossible to answer the question as it is currently written in a very meaningful way since you have not provided any information about what exactly you are trying to do. You should add images showing what you are working on and explain what you have tried to do as far and how that fails.

Comment: I want to make a fan animation for this game. I recreated the location but I can't recreate the shadow effect.
I tried to change the contrast of the black through the hue node, but the contrast of the entire scene was changing, not just the shadows.

Comment: Please edit the question and add all the relevant information. I doubt anyone can provide meaningful help without seeing what you have as far. It's not very helpful to describe images instead of showing them.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve a similar effect in Cycles with negative strength emission.

This effectively absorbs power from the scene, removing light intensity in the vicinity of the source, creating a darkening effect similar to the images.

You can use any object with an emission shader set to a negative value, or use a lamp object with negative strength.

[image]

Comment: Could I achieve the same effect on EEVEE ?

Comment: Only with lights, not emission meshes